# Excel 2010 dynamic named range is replaced with the calculated range

Tags: excel-2010, excel-charts

I am trying an experiment using a series of dynamic named ranges to generate a series of charts under Excel 2010 (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010).

The problem I am running into is that the name of the dynamic range gets replaced by that calculated range after the name is entered.

In this experiment I am using a simple line chart to show the data.

I am selecting the Select Data... pop-up menu option for the chart.
In the Select Data Source dialog box, I enter the named data range into the Chart data range TextBox, and hit enter.

```
I enter ChartNumbers  and it gets replaced with   =Drawings!$E$316:$E$465
```

I have ChartNumbers defined as =OFFSET(Drawings!$E$11,Drawings!$X$4,0,Drawings!$W$4,1)

After setting the chart's data range, any changes I make to the size of the data table are not reflected in the chart.  I have to reapply the named data range to get the chart to show the new data set.

All the examples I have seen, mention nothing about Excel replacing the named data range with the calculated range.

Is there a different method I have to use for charting a named dynamic data range?
Is there a checkbox somewhere to prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues you may be running into when using named data range:

1. You MUST do this to the chart series not the chart data range as Excel will translate the Offset named range to an actual range that will not remain dynamic.
2. When adding the named range to the chart series, you MUST reference both the file name as well as the named range (i.e. `FileName!NamedRange`).

Here is a detailed posting and video to help you out.

[**case-study-creating-a-dynamic-chart-in-excel-using-offset-formula**](http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/case-study-creating-a-dynamic-chart-in-excel-using-offset-formula/)

Let me know if it helps.